# How can PM2 be used to manage a runnable JHipster WAR in production?

Tags: spring-boot, production-environment, systemd, pm2

I'd like to use an executable WAR file in a production environment. I also have several Node.js apps in the same environment for which I use the PM2 process manager to manage the whole lifecycle of (startup on boot, restart on failure, etc.).

PM2 is capable of handling java jar files as well (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41702429/1266411 for details) so it would make sense to use PM2 for this purpose too, but I don't see how a JHipster executable WAR can be configured this way (to be used standalone, without a container).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered just using what spring-boot offers you: running your app as a linux service (systemd or inte.d) http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-service Not sure what pm2 adds to standard Linux services

Comment: Hi Gaël - thx for the reply! Yep, although your link is great, thx! My goal is to unify things as much as (practically) possible so that monitoring, (re-)deployment and long term maintenance are as easy as possible.

Comment: If pm2 is able to manage systemd services, it should be easy but doc is sparse on the subject it seems.

Comment: Yep - I was just checking the same :) My current understanding is that pm2 can be integrated into systemd (with pm2 startup systemd) for startup, but it cannot handle systemd services itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working example. FYI.

```
{
  "apps": [{
    "name": "War",
    "cwd": ".",
    "args": [
      "-jar",
      "/path/to/your.war"
    ],
    "env": {
    },
    "script": "/usr/bin/java",
    "node_args": [],
    "log_date_format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
    "exec_interpreter": "none",
    "exec_mode": "fork"
  }]
}
```